# Равномерная верстка карточек

Tags: html, css3, flexbox

Недавно начал верстать и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Как сделать без отступов, полей и bootstrap равномерную многострочную верстку карточек товаров? Перебрал много вариантов, то все не то, если будет много позиций все поедет.

[image: пример карточек товаров]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[вот ЗДЕСЬ чуть по другому](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MPZxpm?editors=0100)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 4px;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.item p {
  font: 16px/18px normal open-sans;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http:placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, earum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http:placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, earum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http:placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, earum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http:placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, earum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: точно!чел ты крут!спасибо!